# Разный robots.txt joomla 3.x. на страницах

Tags: html, css, joomla3, robots.txt

Всем привет друзья.
Не могу разобраться.
[robots.txt](http://easy-moving.ca/robots.txt) по ссылке перехожу получаю Мой роботс с изменениями.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /bin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
Allow: /component/
Allow: /images/
Allow: /media/
Allow: /modules/mod_as_menu/
Allow: /plugins/content/extravote/assets/
Allow: /templates/as002064/

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.js
Allow: /*.css

Sitemap: https://easy-moving.ca/Sitemap.xml
```

Только что заметил карта сайта не работает тоже. Хотя эта тема Другова вопроса
**---**
[googleConsole](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?utm_source=mft&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=mft-redirect&id=TTPsU-tIRG8HAhEMzWJDNQ&view=fetch-info) выдает что страница не оптимизирован под Мобильные устройства.

Я получаю совершенно другой роботс.Мне бы хотелось понять почему они разные

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /ads/preferences/
Allow: /gpt/
Allow: /pagead/show_ads.js
Allow: /pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js
Allow: /pagead/js/*/show_ads_impl.js
Allow: /static/glade.js
Allow: /static/glade/
Allow: /tag/js/
Disallow: /
Noindex: /
```